# How to get Coded Values from Coded Value Domain in Android Runtime SDK 100.0.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, esri

ArcGIS has a feature to add coded value domains to a field of the feature class.

This feature class can be consumed on Android Device using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android.

I would like to know how to retrieve the coded values from the coded vale domain for a field in that feature class using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android 100.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little complicated to get to the Coded domain of a feature class from the geodatabase. 
Following is an example code to get it. This is for offline geodatabase(Runtime Content), same can be done for geodatabase coming from Service using ServiceFeatureTable class.

```
//Open the geodatabase file
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/testdomainclass.geodatabase"; // path to the offline runtime content on android device
geodatabase = null;
geodatabase = new Geodatabase(path);
geodatabase.loadAsync();

// add feature layer from geodatabase to the ArcGISMap
geodatabaseFeatureTable = geodatabase.getGeodatabaseFeatureTable("points"); // name of the feature class insife the runtime content
geodatabaseFeatureTable.loadAsync();

Field field = geodatabaseFeatureTable.getField("name"); // name of the field for which the domain is created

Domain domain = field.getDomain();
CodedValueDomain codedValueDomain = ((CodedValueDomain) domain);
List<CodedValue> codedvaluelist = codedValueDomain.getCodedValues();
```

In the above example, codedvaluelist object will contain the name and the code which can be retrieved using following code:

```
codedvaluelist.get(0).getName(); //name of codedvalue at 0 index
codedvaluelist.get(0).getCode(); // code of codedvalue at 0 index
```

You can view my geonet post for the same.
[How to get coded values from coded value domain](https://geonet.esri.com/docs/DOC-9971-how-to-get-coded-values-from-coded-value-domain-in-android-runtime-sdk-10000)